# Community user missing the "All" subtab under "All actions"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, community-user

The [Community user's](/users/-1/community) All Actions tab ("Activity" page → "All actions") is missing the "All" subtab that normally is a record of all its actions.

[image: list of tabs for "All actions" which is missing "All"]

Trying to force the correct subtab with `https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=all` redirects me to `https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity`, which shows whichever subtab was last selected.

The subtab being missing does not even happen with users who have no activity:

[image: user with no activity, whose "All actions" has all the tabs including "All"]

<sub>Found by looking for users with username (but not profile-page) spam. I'm not linking the specific user.</sub>

I'm used to the subtab being there, and find it a useful place to see all of Community's actions in a central place  for when I want that. While I'm not sure when it broke, here's a [2015 capture](https://web.archive.org/web/20150907230254/https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity) which shows the subtab in an older version of the profile page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "all" tab was intentionally removed from the Community user profile due to the number of actions that get recorded for the user. Attempting to show that tab was causing issues with overloading, and it was easier to just remove the tab at the time. This may or may not get revisited in the future if we invest in more caching for the All actions section, but at this time it will not be returned.

Comment: Do you know when this happened? I could've sworn I used it semi-recently.

Comment: It was done back on October 6 after we started experiencing SQL timeouts with it.

Comment: @animuson Any possibility of making this a site-specific thing? Seems like smaller sites shouldn’t be a big deal. I’m pretty sure I average more actions per day than the community user at my home site.